# Git: finding "file delete" operations

Tags: git, version-control

How can I programmatically detect when a file has been deleted in git?

Context:  A periodic program generates a text file and checks it in.

Occasionally the program failed and did not generate a file.

Git, when executed, would check in the results, "delete this file."
The next successful run of the program would then add the file.

Process is fixed, and I would like to clean up the spurious delete/add sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I programmatically detect when a file has been deleted in git?

Which program do you wish to use?

If you want to track deleted files withing git (CLI) you have the diff command with the following flags:

```
# using git log
git log --diff-filter=D --summary

# using git status
git status | grep deleted
```

---

The main filter for the diff are:

> ***`A`*** Added
>   ***`D`*** Deleted
>   ***`M`*** Modified
>   ***`R`*** Renamed

There are more filters as well but those are the most common ones.

---

> Git, when executed, would check in the results, "delete this file."

### ***`How to actually delete the file?`***

```
git rm --cached path_to_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --diff-filter=D -- path/to/file.ext
```